# UIView hidden by USearchController

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, navigationbar, uisearchcontroller

I am using UISearchController in a Large header style. But when I push to the next view controller and coming back to the same controller again my UIView hides by navigation bar.

See Video 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tb5Eeni-79uomBGl1GPEcESDSYOfrZ7v

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your error, but I'll post my test code, as it can help you.

I suggest that you write this code in a **BaseViewController: UIViewController** and extend it in your **ViewControllers** for define Large Titles:

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

Define your UISearchController and set your **Instance**.

```
var resultSearchController: UISearchController!

resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
tableView.tableHeaderView = resultSearchController.searchBar
```

**Finally**, **you can try** to close the Search keyboard when the screen disappears, like this:

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    resultSearchController.searchBar.endEditing(true)
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Adding following line in viewwillappear resolves my issue

```
extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```